# need specific output in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to make a query output

Using table, I want the following report, in the format given:

```
-----------     -------
ids < 90000     100,000
ids > 90000     100,000
```

any thoughts?

Comment: you need to provide additional details, what is the table structure, some sample data? What queries have you tried?

Comment: This question is absolutely unanswerable in its current form.  We don't have access to your production database and therefore **have no idea what data you have or what form it's in**.  Furthermore, **we are not able to read your mind** (especially at a distance through the internet) in order to glean this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need you table structure...

Or You Use:
;-)

```
SELECT CONCAT('ids', ' > ','9000'),'100,00'
```

Comment: I apologize. I have thousands of rows of data and I want a simple output of 2 rows. One row shows id's under 90000 and the other shows rows over 900000. And I need the output to look exactly like I showed: 2 rows and 2 columns returned. Was thinking of using DECODE or COUNT or CASE or some mixture of the two

Comment: I spoke with my boss. He clarified some things and I got it. There was a misunderstanding that's why I confused you all. Thanks and my sincerest apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you do something like:

```
(SELECT 'ids < 90000', COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE ID < 9000)
UNION
(SELECT 'ids >= 90000',COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE ID >= 9000)
```

Comment: I need to use CASE in the column calling area and CASE in the GROUP BY

Comment: the case syntax is `case field when value1 then result1 when value2 then result2 else result3 end`

Comment: I want something like this(obviously this is wrong):SELECT
 COUNT(*)
 ,CASE findnums 
WHEN id < '90000' THEN 'ids < 90000'; 
WHEN id > '90000' THEN 'ids > 90000'; FROM TABLE a GROUP BY id

Comment: @Shades - This information would be more useful if it were added to your question.  Also, why is it "obviously wrong"?  What happens when you try it?

Comment: Missing keywords all over the place

Comment: @Shades - The string "Missing keywords all over the place" is not a built-in error message in any RDBMS that I'm aware of.  Look at the error message.  Read it.  Comprehend it.  **Think.**  Address what the error message is saying.  Fix your query.  Try it again.  Repeat.

Comment: ok thanks. I apologize for rushing and not being more descriptive.

Comment: @Shades - Well, it's not too late.  You can edit your question to make it coherent and substantive.